# How to restore VT100 DEC Private modes at end of application?

Tags: terminal, xterm, windows-terminal

Windows Terminal recently added support for [bracketed paste mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode) in the [1.7 release](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.7.572.0). Terminal-based applications can now detect if text received is part of the user typing or it has been pasted and should be processed in bulk.

It seems support for other [Control Sequence Introducers](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_) is missing, so there is no way to retrieve the current state (via Request DEC private mode / DECRQM) or use the stack-based save and restore.

Thus my questions are:

- Is there any other way to restore the bracketed paste mode prior to exit of of my application?
- If not, what would be the desired way I leave the mode? Set or reset?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot amiss with Windows Terminal [#10153](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10153), since the developers were as they say [*"shooting from the hip"*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-shoot-from-the-hip).  There's no study of the available documentation, testing, etc.

The bug report is not talking about [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html), since its DECRQM does actually return a value for [bracketed-paste](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-?-Pm-h:Ps-=-2-0-0-4.1F7D).  Here's a screenshot in [vttest](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html) illustrating that:

[image: screenshot of vttest with DECRQM for xterm private modes]

`XTSAVE` and `XTRESTORE` are old features dating back to December 1986, preceding the VT420 PCTerm (announced in February 1992) by a little over 5 years.  Since DEC participated in developing xterm during the 1980s (see [copyright notice](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/b2ecdc26094793725db0353b0699e4d31446351e/charproc.c#L57)), one might have assumed that its terminals division would have accommodated this.  But that's so long ago, that it's unlikely that someone can point out why that didn't happen.

Like the cursor save/restore, the private-mode save/restore feature does not use a stack.

Back to the question: the point of #10153 is that the Windows Terminal developers choose to not make it xterm-compatible by providing the control responses that would enable an application to determine what state it is in.  Perhaps at some point Windows Terminal will provide a solution.  However, `DECRQM` is a VT320 (and up) feature, while [Windows Terminal](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-ms-terminal) identifies itself as a VT100 (but masquerades as xterm).

Further reading:

- [XTerm Control Sequences (Miscellaneous)](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Miscellaneous)
- [Unit test framework for terminal emulation #1746](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1746)
- [Add support for the DECSCNM Screen Mode #3773](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3773) (eventually resolved)
- [RE: ms-terminal in terminfo.src](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2019-08/msg00004.html) (not resolved, see [#8303](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8303))

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thomas. Do you agree that an application should assume that the state is unset when being started and it doesn't matter whether an application returns the state to the original state before exiting?

Comment: It's not necessary for xterm. If a developer insists on setting `TERM=xterm-256color`, there's no alternative to treating its deficiencies as bugs and looking for a better terminal emulator.

Comment: You seem to indicate that Windows Terminal is maybe not the best choice for a terminal emulator. What would you suggest to use instead (Windows-compatible)?

Comment: Recommending specific programs is off-topic.  (For that matter, lacking programmability in this terminal makes it also off-topic).  If I were making recommendations, I might be biased toward developers who make constructive contributions toward my projects.  So I won't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the discussion I had on the [Windows Terminal bug tracker about the missing support for DECRQM or XTSAVE+XTRESTORE](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10153) :

> It is the implicit assumption that terminal-based application would
> set any desired modes upon start and **reset to the default** at the
> end of the application. Even though this is inefficient it is the way
> around missing support for DECRQM and other ways to query VT-100
> modes.